# React Custom Hook that returns array of Components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

Is this a bad pattern to use with custom hooks?

I'm passing in an array and then looping over that to determine what components will be displayed.

```
import React from "react";
import { Image, Paragraph, Header } from "../../components/Blocks";

export const useBlocks = (blocks) => {
  const items = blocks.map((item: Item) => {
    switch (item.name) {
      case "image":
        return <Image key={item.order} data={item.data} />;
      case "paragraph":
        return <Paragraph key={item.order} data={item.data} />;
      case "heading":
        return <Header key={item.order} data={item.data} />;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  });

  return items;
};
```

Comment: doesnt seem bad to me

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if I'd call it "bad", but it's not very common. You're not using any built-in hooks so I'm not sure why you want it to be hook-like.

Normally, you'd just build something like that as an actual component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Image, Paragraph, Header } from "../../components/Blocks";

export const Blocks = ({blocks}) => {
  return (
    <>
      {blocks.map((item: Item) => {
        switch (item.name) {
          case "image":
            return <Image key={item.order} data={item.data} />;
          case "paragraph":
            return <Paragraph key={item.order} data={item.data} />;
          case "heading":
            return <Header key={item.order} data={item.data} />;
          default:
            return null;
        }
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm all for suggesting edits to my answer, but re-writing the entire things seems a bit... excessive, no?

Answer (score 0):

By implementing this hook I can tell that you are applying Factory Pattern

Check this URL to get more details: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/factory-method

it's useful when it comes to loading dynamic components/classes in the runtime based on a given input. also if component creation is a little bit costly and you want to unify your solution, then it would good choice.